# php how to put single quote in between a string

Tags: php

Using this code to put single quote in between a string but the final string does not show a single quote when echo . I want it be (**'5',**), the php is echo in a javascript array , on javascript alert the array does not show quote but if only php is echo it show the quote

```
 <?php


$conn =mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("we couldn't connect!");
mysql_select_db("test_sql");
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table") or die(mysql_error());
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
 {
        echo "'".$row.['var1']."',";
 }?>
```

Comment: That's strange, it does for me.

Comment: yes this should work, you can also doit like this: $ro=5;
echo "'$ro',"; it's the same just without concatenation

Comment: I dont know  whats the problem  it works , but not in my case :(

Comment: lol your question doesn't makes any sense its vague , please make it clear

Comment: https://eval.in/437190

Comment: sorry for late editing now the complete code is here

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your local enviroment troubles. I test your code here http://www.writephponline.com/ and the result was `'5',`.

By the way, in `php` you can concat variables in double qutes without dots: `"'$ro',";`

Answer (score 0):

As per your need , the modified solution is here .
You should use a local variable in loop so concatenation would be easy.
Use double quote to wrap single quote with backslash and vice versa for JAVSCRIPT  -

**Upadted**

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
         { 
                $ro=$row['var1'];
                $s="\'";
                $s=$s.$ro.$s;
          echo "<script>alert('<?php echo $s; ?>');</script>";
         }
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90301/discussion-between-phpnet-and-rohit-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

Within your example you need to enclosed it within `{}` like as

```
echo "'{$row['var1']}',";
      ^^            ^^
```

After **Second Edit :**

And within your example you've an error

```
echo "'".$row.['var1']."',";
            ^^^
```

It should be

```
echo "'".$row['var1']."',";
          //^^^ (.) removed
```

Comment: Whats not working is your `error_reporting` enabled. If not then simply place `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` at the top after `<?php`

Comment: done but nothing appears , the echo is just without the result